# SQL WHERE statement priority

Tags: mysql

Please explain me priority of this statements in SQL query. What will be first checked and how, I can't understand it well.

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE (deleted_by <> :user AND deleted_by <> :nula) 
    OR deleted_by IS NULL 
   AND IDmessage=:ID
```

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to see what MySQL wants to do.

Comment: Consult some documentation like SQL bible. It is possible that priority rules differ from one SQL flavor to another.

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html

Comment: @N.B. EXPLAIN doesn't explain operator precedence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AND` has higher precedence than `OR`, so it's equivalent to:

```
WHERE (deleted_by <> :user AND deleted_by <> :nula) 
   OR (deleted_by IS NULL AND IDmessage = :ID)
```

I recommend using explicit parentheses whenever you have a mix of `AND` and `OR`, because the results are not always intuitive.